# MongoDB : Complex Arrary field

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d9084841a6168234689aee"),
    "ID" : "01",
    "data" : {
        "Type1" : {
            "value" : "ABC",
            "timestamp" : "2017-03-20 16:01:01"
            },
        "Type2" : {
            "value" : "ccc",
            "timestamp" : "2017-03-20 16:01:01"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get timestamp of each TYPE from mongodb using queryobject using nodejs.
How to get it,Please help.

```
var queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
        var mdb = db.collection("HISTORY").find({{'timestamp':{"$gte":queryObject.fromdate,"$lt" : queryObject.todate}},{"ID":1});
```

Here is my node service:

```
function getHistory(req,res){
    try{
        var queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
        var index=0, resultset = [];
        var db1 = db.collection("HISTORY").find({$and : [{'data.Type1.timestamp':{"$gte": new Date(queryObject.fromdate),"$lt" : new Date(queryObject.todate)}},
            {'data.Type2.timestamp':{"$gte": new Date(queryObject.fromdate),"$lt" : new Date(queryObject.todate)}},
            {'data.Type3.timestamp':{"$gte": new Date(queryObject.fromdate),"$lt" : new Date(queryObject.todate)}},
            {'data.Type4.timestamp':{"$gte": new Date(queryObject.fromdate),"$lt" : new Date(queryObject.todate)}},
            {'data.Type5.timestamp':{"$gte": new Date(queryObject.fromdate),"$lt" : new Date(queryObject.todate)}}
           ]},{"Ino":1,"ID":1,"data":1});
        db1.count(function(err, count) {
            console.log("count" , count);
            db1.each(function(err, doc) {
            if(doc!=null){
                var valdata=doc.alarms;
                var fields = [];
               var queryString ="SELECT field1,NAME FROM details c inner join locdetails l on c.loc_id=l.loc_id where no='"+doc.Ino+"' limit 1;";
               var dtfield1 = null;
               var dtfield2 = null;
                 connection.query(queryString, function(err,result){
                           index++;
                        if(err){
                        }else{
                            if(result.length>0)
                                {
                                     dtfield1 = result[0].field1;
                                     dtfield2 = result[0].NAME;
                                     if(dtfield1!=null){

                                         for (var x in valdata) {
                                             var dt = new Date(valdata[x].timestamp).toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '');
                                             var compareDate = new Date(dt);
                                             if(compareDate.getTime()>=fromDate.getTime()&&compareDate.getTime()<=toDate.getTime()){
                                            resultset.push({"Name":dtfield1,"LName":dtfield2,"Ino":doc.Ino,"ID":doc.ID,"data":x,"datav":valdata[x].value,"Timestamp":valdata[x].timestamp});
                                        }
                                         if(index == count){
                                                res.writeHead(200, {
                                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                                });
                                                res.write(JSON.stringify(resultset));
                                                res.end();
                                            }
                                         }} }}
                    });  
                } else {
            }
        });     
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Exception -- ",err);
    }

}
```

I want data should filter based on timestamp and same can be display in UI and download the displayed data.And also filter should be in UI like current day data and based on time filter also.

Comment: What is your desire result? Please put your desire result as json

Comment: I am display the data in UI and want to download data and display as well based on timstamp filter in UI.Currently i am displaying everything.I want it should be based on timestamp which user can select from UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want search base on both `Type1.timestamp` and `Type2.timestamp`, you should use `$and`. you can change `$and` with `$or` if one matching one of them is enough

```
db.collection("HISTORY").find({
    $and : [{'data.Type1.timestamp':{"$gte": new Date(queryObject.fromdate),"$lt" : new Date(queryObject.todate)}},
            {'data.Type2.timestamp':{"$gte": new Date(queryObject.fromdate),"$lt" : new Date(queryObject.todate)}}
           ]
    },
    {ID:1}, function (err, res){

});
```

Comment: so i need to fire query multiple times.Is there any other method??

Comment: What? Why you need run it multiple times?

Comment: I have update my service ,please check and help for the same.I am new in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation to meet your requirements.

For your initial list which will only show the latest data values of each object, you can use the following pipeline -

```
[
  {
    $project:{
      _id:1,
      ID:1,
      data:{ $objectToArray: "$data" }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind:"$data"
  },
  {
    $sort:{
      "data.v.timestamp":-1
    }
  },
  {
      $group:{
          _id:{
              _id:"$_id",
              ID:"$ID"
          },
          data:{
              $first:"$data"
          }
      }
  },
  {
      $addFields:{
          data:["$data"]
        }
  },
  {
      $addFields:{
          data:{ $arrayToObject: "$data" }
      }
  }
]
```

The result of the aggregation should give you an array of objects like this -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc469c11f8e482416d6edb3"),
    "ID" : "01",
    "data" : {
        "Type2" : {
            "value" : "ccc",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-22T16:01:01.000+06:00")
        }
    }
}
```

As for filtering the collection to get documents with data properties that have timestamp values in the given range, the above pipeline can be modified to acquire it

```
[
  {
    $project:{
      _id:1,
      ID:1,
      data:{ $objectToArray: "$data" }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind:"$data"
  },
  {
    $sort:{
      "data.v.timestamp":-1
    }
  },
  {
      $match:{
         "data.v.timestamp":{ $gt: "start date value", $lt: "end date value"} 
      }
  },
  {
      $group:{
          _id:{
              _id:"$_id",
              ID:"$ID"
          },
          data:{
              $addToSet:"$data"
          }
      }
  },
  {
      $project:{
          _id:"$_id._id",
          ID:"$_id.ID",
          data:{ $arrayToObject: "$data" }
      }
  }
]
```

The result of this aggregation will produce array of objects similar to the one described above. But this time each document's data object will only have properties that match the timestamp condition.

Hope this helps. A final word of advice to you would be to rethink the schema design of the history collection. Because if simplistic date based queries are getting this difficult for you. You can only imagine what the future might hold for you with this design.

Comment: I have updated my question with my node service,can u check it once and help.

Comment: I saw your code and want to confirm a few things from you. 

1. You want to use a date range which is to be used to filter the collection.
2. After which for each document you want to show only the values in the data array that match your exact date rage

Does this sound right?

Comment: correct.Data should be display only which data range should be selected.And first time load it should display only latest data.So it should not load all the data.

Comment: how are you getting the values for the timestamp filters? Are you using a calendar in the UI or do you want display the timestamp values in your history collection's data arrays

Comment: Yes using datepicker calendar.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. I updated my answer. You can have a look now.